# No me funciona jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

¡Hola buenas!

Veréis, me estoy iniciando en jQuery y no sé por qué el siguiente código no me funciona.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("a").click(function () {
                alert("Has pulsado el enlace... Ahora serás enviado a jquery.com");
                window.location = "https://jquery.com/";
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Introducción a jQuery</h1>
        <p>Pagina oficial de jQuery:</p>
        <a href="#">jquery.com</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

En mi carpeta tengo el fichero jQuery correspondiente tal y como muestro en la foto de más abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Un saludo y gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto solo tiene que ver por el orden en el que tienes el llamado a tu script y la etiqueta HTML a la cual haces referencia.

**Explico**

- Tienes el código JS apuntando al evento click de una etiqueta **`a`** que justo en ese momento todavía no existe. *(pues esta declarada debajo de tus 2 scripts)*
- Posterior tienes la creación de dicha etiqueta; pero el código JS que apunta a ella quedó arriba por lo tanto con la lectura del código como es secuencial no identifica dicho nodo y por eso todo el bloque no se ejecuta y tampoco marca error.

Solución propuesta:

- Mueve al final antes de la etiqueta de cierre del body tus 2 scripts, tanto el que llama a jquery como el que procesa la lógica del click y la apertura de la página web en cuestión
- Con lo anterior igual y ayudamos a que la carga no se bloqueé ni se obstaculise por el código JS

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>jQuery</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Introducción a jQuery</h1>
            <p>Pagina oficial de jQuery:</p>
            <a href="#">jquery.com</a>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    
          <script>
                $("a").click(function () {
                    alert("Has pulsado el enlace... Ahora serás enviado a jquery.com");
                    window.location = "https://jquery.com/";
                });
            </script>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Dado que vuestras soluciones funcionan, la tarea que debo hacer es usando la etiqueta ````<style>``` dentro del head, la cosa es que se me olvidó poner el windows.onload.

Ahora funciona, pero si pongo el mismo código js en una página externa, no funciona, no sé si es porqué no puedo meter código jquery en una página externa o algo ...

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Es porque tienes el script en el head y se se está bindeando el evento `onClick` sobre elementos `<a>` que aún no existen en el **dom**.

Para solucionarlo tienes que encapsular tu código JavaScript dentro de `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Es decir, algo como esto:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function () {
  alert("Has pulsado el enlace... Ahora serás enviado a jquery.com");
  window.location = "https://jquery.com/";
});
```

Por otra parte y para evitar bloqueos en la carga de la página, siempre agrega el código javascript justo antes del cierre del body:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Introducción a jQuery</h1>
        <p>Pagina oficial de jQuery:</p>
        <a href="#">jquery.com</a>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a").click(function () {
            alert("Has pulsado el enlace... Ahora serás enviado a jquery.com");
            window.location = "https://jquery.com/";
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizás tu error sea *`window.location`* cuando en realidad es **`window.location.href = 'url'`**

**Editado**

También puedes asignarle la url de esta forma **`window.location.assign('url')`**